# Is it possible to rsync without creating missing files?

Tags: rsync

Is it possible to rsync two directories with only updating existing on both sides files and without creating files that exist in source directory but not exist in destination directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a parameter for that

```
--existing
skip creating new files on receiver
```

Example:

```
$ ll test1/ test2/ test1/: totale 4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 blackman blackman 0 10 apr 11.57 fede
-rw-rw-r--. 1 blackman blackman 7 10 apr 11.58 federico
-rw-rw-r--. 1 blackman blackman 0 10 apr 11.57 federicociao

-rw-rw-r--. 1 blackman blackman 7 10 apr 11.58 federico

rsync -av --existing test1/ test2/
sending incremental file list
./
federico
```